# can we use exported images in google cloud to create a instance from that image outside google cloud

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, operating-system, google-cloud-storage, ubuntu-16.04

lets say i have a vm running with ubuntu 16.04 OS now i have created the image of this vm and i  have exported this image from google cloud  storage 
using the following command from google cloud cli

```
        gcloud compute images export --destination-uri gs://my-bucket/my-image.tar.gz \
--image my-image --project my-project
```

> Question1

Now lets say we are migrating from google cloud to any other cloud service provider can we use 
this image **(my-image.tar.gz)** to create the instance using this image or this image can be used within google cloud only (i.e this image can be used to launch instances(VM'S) within google cloud not outside the google cloud) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think it is possible to create VM using GCP custom images on other Cloud services. Take AWS for an [example](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/vm-import/?nc1=h_ls), the document says:

```
VM Import/Export enables you to easily import virtual machine images 
from your existing environment to Amazon EC2 instances
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes It's possible to use the images of GCE on other Cloud Services, however, keep in mind that in the most of the cases each cloud service have their specifications or limitations about to use custom/external images.